# Modeling Photovoltaic Devices

Tags: solar-cell, modeling

[In this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HkKOHH9iJTA) the man present this schematic (at 6:20):

[image]

And he say that you've to add some capacitors but I don't understand why. I've to model a solar-cell and I have to use the most complete schematic model of a solar-cell, so the question is what is the most complete schematic model of a solar-cell?

Comment: "where can I find" makes this question off topic

Comment: google the subject first and then ask a specific question

Comment: @PkP I've done it. I searched a lot bu I cannot find the thing.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photodiode

Comment: http://www.intusoft.com/nlhtm/nl78.htm#The_Solar_Cell_SPICE_Model

Answer (score 2):

- Voc is the open cct voltage with a small capacitance. This is shown as **U**L(E) for solar energy E at the far right
- The maximum point point starts around 82%Voc and drops with rising (-ve) current. and is the intersection of the knee and optimal load line
- Since this generates current proportional to photo power input, it is negative.
- The load line equivalent resistance at the Max Pwr Point or MPP is related to W=V^2/R where V is ~80% average and R is the sloped load line.  This is near the Rs value of the model.
- critical parameter determined by PV max power [W] spec.

  - Rs = ( Voc*82%)^2 / W approximation
  - tolerance (+4% for low E, -4% high high E from sun) is my rule of thumb
    [image: courtesy Wiki]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45315/discussion-on-answer-by-tony-stewart-modeling-photovoltaic-devices).

Answer (score 0):

The capacitor would be useful in a simulation because a solar cell in no-load (open circuit) configuration is basically a plate capacitor. The plates are the p and n layers of the solar cell semiconductor.

When you attach a load, you first discharge this capacitance from the open circuit voltage (for example 40 volts) to your load voltage (for example 24 volts), and then start getting the photovoltaic current. If your load is always connected, this capacitance would have no meaning: no charge would be able to form to the plates as it is constantly being removed by the load.

Comment: So how will the schematic change?

Comment: I shout ask, what will the two different schematics look like, 1. when no load is connected and 2.when there is a load

Comment: @Popiru, I think the capacitor is in parallel with the diodes 1 and 2.

Comment: Also without load

Comment: Doesn't matter if there's load or no load. I said that under a steady load the capacitance has no relevance. It's only relevant in non-constant loads. Bye.

Comment: is that the only modification?